# Account linking in simulator no longer available?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a voice skill for Google Assistant which requires account linking. Before, I was able to test this in the simulator by going to the Debug tab and there would be a URL that I can use to do the account linking.  Now, that URL is no longer there, and I'm not sure how to do account linking using the simulator anymore.  Is this a bug or did Google intentionally remove this information from the Debug tab of the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I realized that you can just reply "Yes" in the simulator and it opens up the account linking window. Although the link in the Debug tab is still gone, I can still perform account linking. That's good enough.